# How to check and Increase API rate limit on 0x?

Tags: decentralized-exchange, 0x

I am using 0x API for my dex and I am expecting at least 4k users on my app. But I don't see any subscription plan or anything on 0x documentation to increase or at least know my API rate limits. Is it that possible 0x API can handle 4k users or maybe higher. I want to know what is the capacity of the 0x API?

I got one link there no description related to my query, and it is not working also.

https://github.com/0xProject/standard-relayer-api/blob/master/http/v3.md#rate-limits

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your question.

Rate limits and capacity are determined on a case by case basis. We ask that integrators who need access higher rate limits tell us about their project and how they use the 0x API in order for us to understand how we can best collaborate for each use case.

We have a 0x API taker integration request form that you can find here: https://forms.gle/DsmYzzJmRp5myVwj8.